# Measure similar information using Kullback-Leibler (KL) distance matlab code

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am trying implement the distance measurement between two distributions. The detail is described in [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aplufj3nomm9p2s/2013_KL%20distance%20and%20Chan-vese.pdf) and [input image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r7rmr0mw2byzahh/2.bmp) . Let short summarize the idea of the paper:

- The input image is divided into inside region and outside region by using Heaviside function H
- Calculate the distribution inside region and outside region, in which phi is boundary of inside and outside.
- Calculate the Kullback-Leibler distance

I implement that scheme, but I have three problems:

1. Log function in paper is log or log2 in matlab?
2. Log(0) is infinite, But we know that distribution result will return many 0 values. How to ignore it? In my case, I plus with eps value, some people add h1(h1==0)=1, which is correct?
3. Could you see my code? Is it correct? I am not sure about my implementation.

This is my code to implement that scheme:

```
function main()
Img=imread('1.bmp');%please download at above link
Img=double(Img(:,:,1));    
%% Initial boundary
c0=2;  %const value
phi = ones(size(Img(:,:,1))).*c0;
phi(26:32,28:34) = -c0;    
%% Heaviside function
epsilon=1
Hu=0.5*(1+(2/pi)*atan(phi./epsilon));

%% Inside and outside image
inImg=Img.*(1-Hu);
outImg=Img.*(Hu);
%% Let caclulate KL distance
h1 =  histogram(inImg, 256, 0, 255); %Histogram of inside
h2 =  histogram(outImg, 256, 0, 255);%Histogram of outside
lamda1=KLdist(h1,h2) % distance from h1 to h2
lamda2=KLdist(h2,h1) % distance from h2 to h1
end

%%%%%%%%%% function for KL distance%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function [d1,d2]=KLdist(h1,h2)
d1=sum(h1.*log2(h1+eps)-h1.*log2(h2+eps))
d2=sum(h2.*log2(h2+eps)-h2.*log2(h1+eps))
end
%%%%%%%%%%function for histogram calculation%%%%%%
function [h,bins] = histogram(I, n, min, max)
I = I(:);    
range = max - min;
drdb = range / double(n); % dr/db - change in range per bin    
h = zeros(n,1);
bins = zeros(n,1);
for i=1:n
    % note: while the instructions say "within integer round off" I'm leaving
    %       this as float bin edges, to handle the potential float input
    %       ie - say the input was a probability image.
    low = min + (i-1)*drdb; 
    high = min + i*drdb;
    h(i) = sum( (I>=low) .* (I<high) );
  bins(i) = low;
end    
h(n) = h(n) + sum( (I>=(n*drdb)) .* (I<=max) ); % include anything we may have missed in the last bin.

h = h ./ sum(h); % "relative frequency"  
end
```

Comment: if you want a code review, you should go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And the implementation of that scheme. It is more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let answer one by one

1. Log function in paper is log or log2 in matlab?

Ans: This is natural log. In matlab, you just call `log()`

2. Log(0) is infinite, But we know that distribution result will return many 0 values. How to ignore it?

Ans: To ignore the log of zero. You need add some small value as `log(x+eps)` or `log(x+(x==0)*eps)`, where `x` is your values

3. Could you see my code? Is it correct? I am not sure about my implementation.

Ans: Your code looks fine. You can base on my suggestion to improve your code. Good luck